# c# timer was null when trying to close the form, after checking the internet connection

Tags: c#

At the first start I have a function which checks the internet connection. It works only with the messagebox to display the result with this code:

```
//Tikrinam Yra Netas ar ne.
bool con = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
if (con == true)
{
    timer7.Start();
    timer7.Enabled = true;
    timer7.Interval = 10000;
    var popupNotifier = new PopupNotifier();
    popupNotifier.TitleText = " Susscesfully Connected to 3Nematic.NET";
    popupNotifier.TitleColor = Color.BlueViolet;
    //Image
    Image img = Properties.Resources.Cancel_48px; // Cancel
    popupNotifier.Image = img;
    popupNotifier.HeaderColor = Color.Purple;
    // Access Iki:
    popupNotifier.ContentText = " We can't connect you to servers\n " + "Because you're not connected to WiFi Services" + "\n To Connect, you have to get Internet Connection fully working.";
    popupNotifier.IsRightToLeft = false;
    popupNotifier.Popup();
    popupNotifier.ShowCloseButton = true;
    popupNotifier.ShowGrip = true;
    //Parodom, kad yra
}
else
{
    var popupNotifier = new PopupNotifier();
    popupNotifier.TitleText = " Failed to LOG-IN. ";
    popupNotifier.TitleColor = Color.BlueViolet;
    //Image
    Image img = Properties.Resources.Cancel_48px; // Cancel
    popupNotifier.Image = img;
    popupNotifier.HeaderColor = Color.Purple;
    // Access Iki:
    popupNotifier.ContentText = " We can't connect you to servers\n " + "Because you're not connected to WiFi Services" + "\n To Connect, you have to get Internet Connection fully working.";
    popupNotifier.IsRightToLeft = false;
    popupNotifier.Popup();
    popupNotifier.ShowCloseButton = true;
    popupNotifier.ShowGrip = true;
    //Isjungs ir  nieko nerodys, tai reik timerio kursim timer7 koki
}
```

I'm also adding a popup. At the end I have a timer which is not yet in the code. That timer will close the app after 10sec of popup display. When the internet is on, the popup does work. When the internet is off however, I'm getting the form paused and I get this error: `System.Net.WebException: 'The remote name could not be resolved: 'google.com''`

This is the function, to get everyone IP, which is using the app.

```
//Gavimas ip
private string Gaunamip()
{
    string ip = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://google.com");
    ip = ip.Replace("\n", "");
    return ip;
}
```

[image]

**P.S** *Thanks for helping.*

Comment: What does this have to do with a timer? This is awfully confusing

Comment: When you are with no internet the popup opens and if i would use application.exit the popup wouldn't pop, and i do a timer which will get 10 sec. to work with the popup, after time past, the app will exit, and the popup closes

Comment: If you don't have a internet adapter enabled or cable plugged in or general there is something wrong with your internet. You can have exceptions when trying to  acces web resources . Change your code to handles these exceptions. 
Your code explicitly states '3Nematic.NET' you might want to explicitly try to acces a resources in that domain as a internet check.